# When using QUERY, how can I make it so that data moves together when using filter?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am creating a tool for a video game I play.

[Link to the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8jBi_7BFIsoX-caDsOg0vCY46G9PQdSU3XsdAu5ktw/copy) (Please make a copy to edit so that this copy stays intact for additional helpers).

Sheet 1 is “**Choose Owned**”. It contains a list of all of the champions available in the game and includes their attributes.

- Column A contains checkboxes. Checking a checkbox indicates that the user owns that champion, and brings it to Sheet 2.

Sheet 2 is called “**Owned**”. It contains a list of the champions checked off in “Choose Owned” (aka the champions the user owns). “Owned” includes the champion attributes too, as first seen in “Choose Owned”.

- Beyond those same attributes, “Owned” contains 8 additional columns.
  These columns are from Columns G:N and are labeled ‘Level’, ‘Rank’,
  ‘Ascension Lvl’, and ‘Team Label(s)’ (‘Team Label(s)’ takes up
  columns J:N). This data is all unique information and requires the
  user to input the information themselves depending on their
  champions.

Because there are so many champions, I want the user to be able to use the Filter function in “Owned” so they can easily locate the champion they need or sort the table however they wish.

However, because I use the `QUERY` function to get the data from “Choose Owned”, the Filter function tends to break. The most obvious error comes when you try to sort A-Z or Z-A; this simply cannot be done. I was fine with this, and have even included a note at the top telling the user to avoid sorting alphabetically.

Everything else works correctly until the user tries to add a new champion from “Choose Owned”. When the champion is added to “Owned”, the additional, unique data in columns G:N go out of order because they don’t move with their original champions.

**Example:**

- I choose my champions. These champions are copied to “Owned”.
- I pick their relative data in columns G:N.
- A few days later, I obtain new champions and check them off in “Choose Owned” so they are added to “Owned”.  However, when I do this, the champions stay in the same order as they are in “Choose Owned”, and columns G:N do not move with their champions so now, that information is with the wrong champion.

I want the additional data (G:N) to move with their champions when the table is edited due to champions being added. Or, in other words, I want those columns to stay linked to the first columns.

If there is a different way to achieve all of this like if I have to use a function other than `QUERY`, that is fine!

Please share any solutions you may have. I would prefer to not use a script but will consider the idea if it works.

Comment: I would be easier with a script

Comment: Do you know of a script that will work, or are you just saying that in general?

Comment: I can think of how to write a script that would work. The script would use the method `insertRowAfter(afterPosition)` in order to insert new champions.In this way, the additional data would move with the already existing champions. You could specify the position where the new champions would be inserted dynamically, e.g. alphabetically.

Comment: If you are interested in this solution, I can sketch a workflow for it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue within Google Sheets and it's solvable in 2 ways:

- either by introducing a common value (unique ID) and then linking the manual input to query and aligning it by ID
- or easier approach in your case - using timestamp/linear ID so every new entry would be added to the bottom and then the query would be sorted based on this order.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by either of those. Could you elaborate? It's promising that you seem to know what I'm talking about at least! :)

Edit: I know what you mean by the timestamp thing actually. How would you suggest going about doing that? (Still not sure what you meant by the first bullet though)

Comment: first bullet is basically this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120338/186471